# Getting pixel RGB values 0-255 in C++ using Magick++

Tags: c++, magick++

I'm using C++ and Magick++. I need to get red, green and blue values from pixel but anything I do keeps getting me values over 255 or decimal values. Next code gives me decimal values

```
ColorRGB rgb(someImage.pixelColor(x, y));
cout << rgb.red();
cout << rgb.green();
cout << rgb.blue();
```

Also I don't know if I can use Quantum values like this

```
image.pixelColor(x, y).redQuantum();
```

to get red value between 0 and 255 and not decimal. Does anyone know how to get this or calculate (I understand there's probably no function for this so I need to calculate it myself)

Comment: Try `cout << static_cast<long>(rgb.red() * 255);`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Magick++ documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Color.html), it appears that when using `ColorRGB` the color values are represented as a decimal value between zero and one.

This actually makes a lot of sense since it also appears that you have a choice of which depth of color you would like to use.  Rather than locking you into values from zero through 255, the decimal 0.0-1.0 can be easily scaled to any color depth.

If you are sure that you want to see it from 0-255 even if the underlying color depth is, say, 32 bit, you can easily write a transformation function.

**Update**

Here's an example of how you can scale the value:

```
 uint8_t red = (uint8_t)(rgb.red() * 255);
```

This will scale it to an 8 but integer between zero and 255.

Comment: Was looking for a example code on how to transform this because it's my first time working with colours, so I don't know how all this works (no knowledge about this), but this was also helpful, thank you.